# Match two plots with different length

Tags: r, plot, time-series, match

I have two plots with different length which do not match. How can I match them since they have similar shape?

The code I used is the following:

```
plot(sort(time1),d_fx,type="l",col="red", xlab="Time[s]",ylab="X[m/s2]",xlim=c(0,35))
lines(time2,d_mx,col="blue",xlim=c(0,35),yaxt='n',lty=2)
```

Getting the plot below
[image]

**Data:**

```
time1 <- c(0, 0.108999967575073, 0.218000173568726, 0.328000068664551, 
           0.437000036239624, 0.546000003814697, 0.624000072479248, 0.702000141143799, 
           0.811000108718872, 0.920000076293945, 1.02999997138977, 1.13900017738342, 
           1.2480001449585, 1.35700011253357, 1.46600008010864, 1.57599997520447, 
           1.65400004386902, 1.76300001144409, 1.87199997901917, 1.98100018501282, 
           2.09000015258789, 2.20000004768372, 2.30900001525879, 2.41799998283386, 
           2.54299998283386, 2.65200018882751, 2.76100015640259, 2.88600015640259, 
           2.99500012397766, 3.12000012397766, 3.24500012397766, 3.37000012397766, 
           3.49400019645691, 3.61900019645691, 3.74400019645691, 3.86900019645691, 
           3.99400019645691, 4.11800003051758, 4.24300003051758, 4.36800003051758, 
           4.50800013542175, 4.61800003051758, 4.74200010299683, 4.86700010299683, 
           4.99200010299683, 5.11700010299683, 5.24200010299683, 5.3510000705719, 
           5.46000003814697, 5.58500003814697, 5.71000003814697, 5.83400011062622, 
           5.95900011062622, 6.08500003814697, 6.58400011062622, 6.70900011062622, 
           6.83400011062622, 9.26699995994568, 9.39199995994568, 9.51699995994568, 
           9.64199995994568, 11.1860001087189, 11.3110001087189, 11.3580000400543, 
           11.4049999713898, 11.529000043869, 11.654000043869, 11.779000043869, 
           11.8259999752045, 11.8730001449585, 11.9969999790192, 12.0440001487732, 
           12.1690001487732, 12.2940001487732, 12.4190001487732, 12.4650001525879, 
           12.5120000839233, 12.6210000514984, 12.6679999828339, 12.7929999828339, 
           12.9179999828339, 13.0429999828339, 13.1670000553131, 13.2920000553131, 
           13.4170000553131, 13.5420000553131, 13.6670000553131, 13.7130000591278, 
           13.7599999904633, 13.8849999904633, 14.0099999904633, 14.0570001602173, 
           14.180999994278, 14.305999994278, 14.353000164032, 14.478000164032, 
           14.603000164032, 14.7120001316071, 14.7590000629425, 14.8050000667572, 
           14.8519999980927, 14.8990001678467, 15.0240001678467, 15.0710000991821, 
           15.1950001716614, 15.3359999656677, 15.4609999656677, 15.6010000705719, 
           15.710000038147, 15.819000005722, 15.8660001754761, 15.9130001068115, 
           16.0220000743866, 16.069000005722, 16.2090001106262, 16.2560000419617, 
           16.3970000743866, 16.4430000782013, 16.4900000095367, 16.6310000419617, 
           16.7710001468658, 16.8180000782013, 16.9580001831055, 17.0050001144409, 
           17.0520000457764, 17.0989999771118, 17.2239999771118, 17.3650000095367, 
           17.4120001792908, 17.5520000457764, 17.5989999771118, 17.739000082016, 
           17.8800001144409, 18.0199999809265, 18.1600000858307, 18.3010001182556, 
           18.4409999847412, 18.5659999847412, 18.6130001544952, 18.7380001544952, 
           18.7840001583099, 18.9250001907349, 19.0650000572205, 19.2060000896454, 
           19.3460001945496, 19.4860000610352, 19.6270000934601, 19.6740000247955, 
           19.7980000972748, 19.9230000972748, 20.0480000972748, 20.0950000286102, 
           20.2200000286102, 20.3440001010895, 20.3910000324249, 20.4379999637604, 
           20.4850001335144, 20.625, 20.7660000324249, 20.8120000362396, 
           20.9530000686646, 21.0930001735687, 21.2339999675751, 21.3580000400543, 
           21.4360001087189, 21.5610001087189, 21.6080000400543, 21.7330000400543, 
           21.7799999713898, 21.904000043869, 22.029000043869, 22.154000043869, 
           22.279000043869, 22.404000043869, 22.5130000114441, 22.5600001811981, 
           22.6840000152588, 22.8400001525879, 22.9810001850128, 23.1370000839233, 
           23.2770001888275, 23.4020001888275, 23.5270001888275, 23.6520001888275, 
           23.8230001926422, 23.9480001926422, 24.0730001926422, 24.1980001926422, 
           24.7440001964569, 24.9000000953674, 25.055999994278, 25.2120001316071, 
           25.3359999656677, 25.4609999656677, 25.5859999656677, 25.7109999656677, 
           25.8359999656677, 25.960000038147, 26.085000038147, 26.210000038147, 
           26.319000005722, 26.4279999732971, 26.5380001068115, 26.6470000743866, 
           26.7560000419617, 26.8650000095367, 26.9739999771118, 27.0840001106262, 
           27.1930000782013, 27.3020000457764, 27.4110000133514, 27.5199999809265, 
           27.6300001144409, 27.739000082016, 27.8480000495911, 27.9570000171661, 
           28.0659999847412, 28.1760001182556, 28.2850000858307, 28.3940000534058, 
           28.5030000209808, 28.6119999885559, 28.7220001220703, 28.8310000896454, 
           28.9400000572205, 29.0490000247955, 29.1579999923706, 29.268000125885, 
           29.3770000934601, 29.4860000610352, 29.5950000286102, 29.7039999961853, 
           29.8140001296997, 29.9230000972748, 30.0320000648499, 30.1410000324249, 
           30.25, 30.3600001335144, 30.4690001010895, 30.5780000686646, 
           30.7180001735687, 30.8740000724792, 31.0299999713898, 31.1860001087189, 
           31.2330000400543, 31.3580000400543, 31.4830000400543, 31.6080000400543, 
           31.7320001125336, 31.8570001125336, 31.9820001125336, 32.1070001125336, 
           32.2320001125336, 32.3410000801086, 32.4500000476837, 32.5590000152588, 
           32.6679999828339, 32.7780001163483, 32.8870000839233, 32.9960000514984, 
           33.1050000190735, 33.2139999866486, 33.324000120163, 33.433000087738, 
           33.5420000553131, 33.6510000228882, 33.7599999904633, 33.8700001239777, 
           33.9790000915527, 34.0880000591278, 34.1970000267029, 34.305999994278, 
           34.4160001277924, 34.5250000953674, 34.6340000629425, 34.7430000305176, 
           34.8519999980927, 35.0080001354218, 35.1640000343323, 35.3200001716614, 
           35.4760000705719, 35.710000038147, 35.8510000705719, 37.5040001869202, 
           37.6600000858307, 37.8159999847412, 37.9409999847412, 38.0659999847412, 
           38.1909999847412, 38.3159999847412, 38.4400000572205, 38.5500001907349, 
           38.6590001583099, 38.768000125885, 38.893000125885, 39.0020000934601, 
           39.1270000934601, 39.7980000972748, 39.9539999961853, 40.0940001010895, 
           40.25, 40.4060001373291, 40.5310001373291, 40.6560001373291, 
           40.7799999713898, 40.9049999713898, 41.0299999713898, 41.1549999713898, 
           41.2799999713898, 41.404000043869, 41.5140001773834, 41.6230001449585, 
           41.7009999752045, 41.8100001811981, 41.8880000114441, 41.9660000801086, 
           42.0440001487732, 42.1219999790192, 42.2000000476837, 42.3090000152588, 
           42.4179999828339, 42.5280001163483, 42.6370000839233, 42.7150001525879, 
           42.7929999828339, 42.8710000514984, 42.949000120163, 43.0270001888275, 
           43.0889999866486, 43.1360001564026, 43.2450001239777, 43.2920000553131, 
           43.3540000915527, 43.4480001926422, 43.5099999904633)
time2 <- c(0, 0.002, 0.038, 0.073, 0.117, 0.143, 0.179, 0.214, 0.249, 
           0.284, 0.32, 0.355, 0.39, 0.426, 0.468, 0.496, 0.531, 0.566, 
           0.602, 0.637, 0.673, 0.707, 0.743, 0.778, 0.82, 0.848, 0.884, 
           0.919, 0.954, 0.99, 1.025, 1.06, 1.095, 1.131, 1.173, 1.201, 
           1.236, 1.272, 1.307, 1.342, 1.377, 1.412, 1.448, 1.483, 1.525, 
           1.553, 1.589, 1.886, 1.953, 2.02, 2.088, 2.154, 2.222, 2.289, 
           2.356, 2.423, 2.49, 2.557, 2.624, 2.692, 2.759, 2.826, 2.893, 
           2.96, 3.028, 3.095, 3.162, 3.23, 3.297, 3.363, 3.43, 3.498, 3.565, 
           3.632, 3.708, 3.766, 3.833, 3.901, 3.968, 4.034, 4.102, 4.169, 
           4.237, 4.305, 4.37, 4.438, 4.504, 4.572, 4.639, 4.707, 4.774, 
           4.841, 4.907, 4.974, 5.042, 5.109, 5.176, 5.245, 5.312, 5.378, 
           5.445, 5.514, 5.579, 5.647, 5.713, 5.78, 5.847, 5.915, 5.982, 
           6.05, 6.139, 6.198, 6.25, 6.318, 6.399, 6.452, 6.519, 6.586, 
           6.654, 6.721, 7.037, 7.12, 7.12, 7.165, 7.174, 7.231, 7.244, 
           7.281, 7.315, 7.381, 7.385, 7.45, 7.456, 7.517, 7.527, 7.562, 
           7.638, 7.642, 7.678, 7.713, 7.797, 7.799, 7.904, 7.906, 7.907, 
           7.957, 7.974, 8.014, 8.045, 8.094, 8.115, 8.151, 8.186, 8.254, 
           8.257, 8.358, 8.358, 8.362, 8.397, 8.432, 8.468, 8.503, 8.538, 
           8.578, 8.609, 8.664, 8.683, 8.744, 8.75, 8.812, 8.82, 8.887, 
           8.891, 8.961, 8.968, 9.019, 9.036, 9.072, 9.107, 9.142, 9.178, 
           9.22, 9.248, 9.329, 9.332, 9.401, 9.402, 9.435, 9.459, 9.495, 
           9.53, 9.596, 9.601, 9.667, 9.671, 9.707, 9.792, 9.792, 9.827, 
           9.864, 9.918, 9.933, 9.997, 10.004, 10.073, 10.075, 10.155, 10.155, 
           10.179, 10.215, 10.29, 10.29, 10.615, 10.682, 10.749, 10.816, 
           10.884, 10.951, 11.047, 11.084, 11.152, 11.219, 11.286, 11.353, 
           11.429, 11.488, 11.555, 11.622, 11.689, 11.756, 11.823, 11.892, 
           11.958, 12.025, 12.092, 12.159, 12.226, 12.293, 12.361, 12.427, 
           12.495, 12.562, 12.647, 12.698, 12.764, 12.83, 12.898, 13.01, 
           13.038, 13.099, 13.166, 13.233, 13.301, 13.368, 13.466, 13.502, 
           13.569, 13.643, 13.704, 13.771, 13.857, 13.905, 13.972, 14.039, 
           14.124, 14.174, 14.25, 14.307, 14.376, 14.442, 14.509, 14.577, 
           14.654, 14.727, 14.79, 14.85, 14.917, 14.996, 15.052, 15.113, 
           15.184, 15.26, 15.315, 15.382, 15.469, 15.555, 15.591, 15.65, 
           15.717, 15.785, 15.868, 15.919, 15.986, 16.054, 16.157, 16.243, 
           16.285, 16.322, 16.389, 16.46, 16.541, 16.658, 16.658, 16.725, 
           16.793, 16.859, 16.926, 17.014, 17.068, 17.127, 17.195, 17.263, 
           17.352, 17.397, 17.463, 17.53, 17.598, 17.665, 17.734, 17.803, 
           17.867, 17.934, 18.011, 18.071, 18.188, 18.218, 18.269, 18.336, 
           18.404, 18.47, 18.538, 18.605, 18.676, 18.74, 18.839, 18.908, 
           18.949, 19.008, 19.075, 19.142, 19.263, 19.294, 19.343, 19.411, 
           19.499, 19.545, 19.639, 19.684, 19.746, 19.814, 19.881, 19.948, 
           20.041, 20.084, 20.149, 20.217, 20.284, 20.351, 20.418, 20.485, 
           20.552, 20.62, 20.687, 20.754, 20.858, 20.899, 20.955, 21.022, 
           21.089, 21.159, 21.224, 21.291, 21.358, 21.425, 21.493, 21.559, 
           21.627, 21.694, 21.761, 21.854, 21.895, 21.962, 22.03, 22.097, 
           22.186, 22.26, 22.32, 22.373, 22.442, 22.52, 22.607, 22.662, 
           22.701, 22.768, 22.835, 22.903, 22.969, 23.037, 23.103, 23.17, 
           23.238, 23.305, 23.374, 23.439, 23.506, 23.574, 23.642, 23.723, 
           23.775, 23.842, 23.909, 23.977, 24.044, 24.111, 24.178, 24.246, 
           24.323, 24.381, 24.471, 24.525, 24.581, 24.648, 24.716, 24.783, 
           24.888, 24.928, 24.984, 25.061, 25.118, 25.185, 25.265, 25.327, 
           25.387, 25.454, 25.524)

d_fx <- c(0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 0.312, 0.333333333333333, 
          0.312, 0.333333333333333, 0.312, 0.312, 0.333333333333333, 0.312, 
          0.312, 0.333333333333333, 0.312, 0.312, 0.292, 0.312, 0.312, 
          0.312, 0.354666666666667, 0.333333333333333, 0.292, 0.312, 0.312, 
          0.312, 0.312, 0.333333333333333, 0.312, 0.333333333333333, 0.312, 
          0.312, 0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 
          0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 
          0.333333333333333, 0.312, 0.312, 0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 
          0.312, 0.312, 0.292, 0.312, 0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 
          0.292, 0.292, 0.312, 0.333333333333333, 0.312, 0.312, 0.333333333333333, 
          0.312, 0.312, 0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 
          0.333333333333333, 0.312, 0.312, 0.270666666666667, 0.5, 0.333333333333333, 
          0.396, 0.396, 0.292, 0.270666666666667, 0.333333333333333, 0.312, 
          0, 0.0626666666666666, 0, 0.208, 0.0413333333333333, 0.437333333333333, 
          0.5, 0.562666666666667, 0.562666666666667, 0.792, 0.854666666666667, 
          0.896, 0.917333333333333, 0.917333333333333, 0.812, 0.750666666666667, 
          0.729333333333333, 0.604, 0.666666666666667, 0.541333333333333, 
          0.478666666666667, 0.292, 0.270666666666667, 0.312, 0.229333333333333, 
          0.270666666666667, 0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 
          0.396, 0.584, 0.645333333333333, 0.708, 0.792, 0.917333333333333, 
          0.917333333333333, 0.896, 0.729333333333333, 0.604, 0.812, 0.584, 
          0.688, 0.584, 0.521333333333333, 0.270666666666667, 0.521333333333333, 
          0.249333333333333, 0.208, 0.0826666666666667, 0.229333333333333, 
          0.166666666666667, 0.188, 0.166666666666667, 0.208, 0.249333333333333, 
          0.229333333333333, 0.374666666666667, 0.333333333333333, 0.541333333333333, 
          0.478666666666667, 0.478666666666667, 0.584, 0.812, 0.874666666666667, 
          0.812, 0.874666666666667, 0.833333333333333, 0.688, 0.666666666666667, 
          0.625333333333333, 0.729333333333333, 0.604, 0.521333333333333, 
          0.562666666666667, 0.396, 0.354666666666667, 0.417333333333333, 
          0.333333333333333, 0.417333333333333, 0.374666666666667, 0.478666666666667, 
          0.541333333333333, 0.604, 0.541333333333333, 0.584, 0.645333333333333, 
          0.645333333333333, 0.833333333333333, 0.833333333333333, 1, 0.874666666666667, 
          0.978666666666667, 0.958666666666667, 0.812, 0.833333333333333, 
          0.917333333333333, 0.833333333333333, 0.729333333333333, 0.729333333333333, 
          0.645333333333333, 0.625333333333333, 0.541333333333333, 0.625333333333333, 
          0.750666666666667, 0.666666666666667, 0.562666666666667, 0.417333333333333, 
          0.541333333333333, 0.458666666666667, 0.437333333333333, 0.417333333333333, 
          0.249333333333333, 0.188, 0.333333333333333, 0.249333333333333, 
          0.208, 0.270666666666667, 0.292, 0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 
          0.312, 0.312, 0.312, 0.333333333333333, 0.312, 0.333333333333333, 
          0.312, 0.312, 0.312, 0.333333333333333, 0.312, 0.312, 0.333333333333333, 
          0.312, 0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 0.312, 0.312, 0.312, 
          0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 0.312, 0.374666666666667, 
          0.312, 0.312, 0.312, 0.312, 0.312, 0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 
          0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 0.312, 
          0.312, 0.312, 0.333333333333333, 0.292, 0.312, 0.333333333333333, 
          0.270666666666667, 0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 0.312, 
          0.333333333333333, 0.312, 0.333333333333333, 0.312, 0.312, 0.333333333333333, 
          0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 0.312, 0.333333333333333, 
          0.312, 0.312, 0.312, 0.312, 0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 
          0.312, 0.312, 0.312, 0.312, 0.312, 0.333333333333333, 0.312, 
          0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 0.312, 0.333333333333333, 
          0.333333333333333, 0.312, 0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 
          0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 0.292, 0.312, 0.312, 0.312, 
          0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 
          0.292, 0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 
          0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 0.312, 0.333333333333333, 
          0.312, 0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 0.312, 0.333333333333333, 
          0.312, 0.354666666666667, 0.333333333333333, 0.312, 0.312, 0.312, 
          0.333333333333333, 0.354666666666667, 0.333333333333333, 0.312, 
          0.312, 0.312, 0.312, 0.333333333333333, 0.312, 0.312, 0.312, 
          0.312, 0.333333333333333, 0.312, 0.333333333333333, 0.312, 0.312, 
          0.312, 0.333333333333333, 0.312, 0.312, 0.312, 0.333333333333333, 
          0.333333333333333, 0.312, 0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 
          0.333333333333333, 0.312, 0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 
          0.312, 0.333333333333333, 0.312, 0.312, 0.312, 0.333333333333333, 
          0.333333333333333, 0.312)

d_mx <- c(0.451496398515711, 0.481153389527666, 0.481354930383724, 0.477927889020427, 
          0.475307857891679, 0.482967257232184, 0.478835669683005, 0.476114021315909, 
          0.471376964388239, 0.476718643884082, 0.479843373963292, 0.477424036880283, 
          0.472989291236699, 0.475307857891679, 0.478936440111034, 0.471880816528383, 
          0.477020955168168, 0.473292449331105, 0.481052619099637, 0.476214791743938, 
          0.476114021315909, 0.47369553104322, 0.477323266452254, 0.481858782523867, 
          0.473897071899277, 0.473897071899277, 0.481959552951896, 0.47923875139512, 
          0.475207087463651, 0.476013250887881, 0.478129429876484, 0.480750307815551, 
          0.476718643884082, 0.480347226103436, 0.479339521823149, 0.47923875139512, 
          0.474904776179565, 0.475912480459852, 0.474703235323507, 0.476214791743938, 
          0.478532511588599, 0.477524807308312, 0.475408628319708, 0.477121725596197, 
          0.476315562171967, 0.476315562171967, 0.476718643884082, 0.476214791743938, 
          0.476315562171967, 0.475106317035622, 0.476214791743938, 0.476114021315909, 
          0.476214791743938, 0.475509398747737, 0.475509398747737, 0.476214791743938, 
          0.476013250887881, 0.476920184740139, 0.475710939603794, 0.475710939603794, 
          0.475811710031823, 0.476214791743938, 0.476819414312111, 0.476920184740139, 
          0.476718643884082, 0.475307857891679, 0.476416332599996, 0.474703235323507, 
          0.476617873456053, 0.474904776179565, 0.476315562171967, 0.475106317035622, 
          0.475106317035622, 0.474804005751536, 0.475408628319708, 0.475610169175766, 
          0.475811710031823, 0.475307857891679, 0.475610169175766, 0.476315562171967, 
          0.475610169175766, 0.475509398747737, 0.476315562171967, 0.476214791743938, 
          0.476819414312111, 0.475005546607593, 0.475811710031823, 0.477121725596197, 
          0.476617873456053, 0.476114021315909, 0.476214791743938, 0.476718643884082, 
          0.476114021315909, 0.476214791743938, 0.476819414312111, 0.475610169175766, 
          0.475912480459852, 0.474904776179565, 0.476517103028024, 0.475610169175766, 
          0.475005546607593, 0.475912480459852, 0.474501694467449, 0.477625577736341, 
          0.494759090932186, 0.416952465149521, 0.550796763829683, 0.431969799356763, 
          0.403649075029088, 0.477121725596197, 0.439326887413181, 0.460794375824582, 
          0.5, 0.457972803839777, 0.372707472762346, 0.403145222888944, 
          0.43942765784121, 0.542632665538715, 0.461298227964725, 0.498689984435626, 
          0.860915639062344, 0.684035593131352, 0.770913251057243, 1, 0.663172727288124, 
          0.79903243452886, 0.987805084587883, 0.646139984520307, 0.863233358907005, 
          0.71527950668218, 0.750050385214014, 0.683834052275295, 0.777364252071721, 
          0.719915793181822, 0.772224113431936, 0.61721463762446, 0.583048381660798, 
          0.439629198697267, 0.81737603967137, 0.47288852080867, 0.607135901200946, 
          0.537895608611045, 0.419271031804502, 0.475307857891679, 0.448801001268522, 
          0.42824044670938, 0.430357472508303, 0.412517719505937, 0.399415870241561, 
          0.358798613263421, 0.34126201835546, 0.27192095533753, 0.336121879715675, 
          0.236142372525409, 0.327857857806998, 0.242189445017453, 0.300444067331582, 
          0.22727288123824, 0.256904467940608, 0.207720877769705, 0.16901910573443, 
          0.152388597868409, 0.207116255201532, 0.13313890568396, 0.149163944171489, 
          0.178391602351423, 0.159948073591204, 0.118927734900949, 0.0695426038739878, 
          0, 0.0286238824220808, 0.0472689520383571, 0.0770013091687541, 
          0.153800230671131, 0.0518044681099702, 0.103608089409621, 0.253880508289426, 
          0.15712565479608, 0.324632357299759, 0.189981895195368, 0.38832942953776, 
          0.265974653273515, 0.384297765606291, 0.30145177161187, 0.337634282946426, 
          0.379459938250592, 0.306491139823626, 0.42420878277791, 0.494053697935985, 
          0.368272727118762, 0.375630661985499, 0.330377118507717, 0.464725269328022, 
          0.469260785399635, 0.458879737692035, 0.457468951699633, 0.503326270935268, 
          0.40586602444572, 0.536182511334556, 0.402136671798337, 0.513001925646667, 
          0.546765099898213, 0.593933281508542, 0.645031509811991, 0.615703081204029, 
          0.663878967094645, 0.644628428099876, 0.864443450853669, 0.558556933598216, 
          0.695726656403326, 0.733017642446198, 0.838238905514598, 0.54545508433384, 
          0.786031355692513, 0.72404822754132, 0.757710631364838, 0.734630816104977, 
          0.732211479021968, 0.750555084164478, 0.74642264980498, 0.73997249560082, 
          0.661459630011635, 0.671336825579091, 0.637069799187401, 0.622959398832418, 
          0.54464892090961, 0.387724806969588, 0.412719260361995, 0.352348459059261, 
          0.307196532819828, 0.277464175689431, 0.156218720943821, 0.163878967094645, 
          0.16428204880676, 0.146139984520307, 0.135658166384679, 0.167708243359737, 
          0.116206933344173, 0.0664187206050968, 0.0550299686172096, 0.0176382121463085, 
          0.0277161017595025, 0.0540214175266026, 0.113182973692991, 0.130618798172922, 
          0.175872341650704, 0.00181471451483701, 0.154404853239304, 0.101794221705103, 
          0.249244221789784, 0.235537749957236, 0.209030893334079, 0.217194144814726, 
          0.286938289544772, 0.299637903907352, 0.275751078412942, 0.309715793520546, 
          0.385406240314607, 0.388027118253674, 0.361721802486574, 0.513203466502724, 
          0.479339521823149, 0.476013250887881, 0.491534437235266, 0.535980970478499, 
          0.666398227795363, 0.649970107595719, 0.746523420233008, 0.701068335899169, 
          0.78865223363158, 0.838641987226713, 0.884196995178262, 0.898307395533245, 
          0.70731779605759, 0.902136671798337, 0.857387827271018, 0.902237442226366, 
          0.927635824141207, 0.990929814667094, 0.887220954829444, 0.830880970647861, 
          0.698448304770421, 0.785325962696312, 0.656218720943821, 0.577202850024812, 
          0.497883821011396, 0.496069953306879, 0.480447996531465, 0.581535978430048, 
          0.517436671290251, 0.460492064540495, 0.428038905853322, 0.400222033665791, 
          0.34609984571116, 0.27434029242054, 0.190183436051425, 0.201269876755226, 
          0.207015484773504, 0.138279044323746, 0.175872341650704, 0.11882696447292, 
          0.128502619184318, 0.151985516156294, 0.120843219843814, 0.122858628404389, 
          0.19300585484655, 0.216992603958669, 0.120742449415786, 0.210139368042395, 
          0.181717873286691, 0.250151155642043, 0.322717719167213, 0.303366409744416, 
          0.300141756047496, 0.410099229233247, 0.500605469378492, 0.47923875139512, 
          0.492743682371611, 0.459484360260208, 0.526607627051186, 0.527212249619359, 
          0.502419337083009, 0.616509244628259, 0.686354159786333, 0.651985516156294, 
          0.800141756047496, 0.810724344611153, 0.815259013872447, 0.767285515648208, 
          0.964523728471965, 0.792179198612586, 0.911409244797621, 0.922092603789307, 
          0.910603081373391, 0.903749845457117, 0.842168952207719, 0.850534591354744, 
          0.79822627110463, 0.725257472677665, 0.756199074944407, 0.771719414481473, 
          0.735336209101179, 0.763556163000825, 0.661560400439664, 0.600584976568759, 
          0.556743065893698, 0.624874036964964, 0.444769337337053, 0.339649691507001, 
          0.457267410843576, 0.368776579258906, 0.313848227880044, 0.396996533158552, 
          0.31415053916413, 0.21608567010641, 0.181717873286691, 0.141503698020666, 
          0.0899016175770725, 0.0996780427164998, 0.187764945778735, 0.285829814836456, 
          0.10763975334109, 0.166398227795363, 0.241685592877309, 0.368474267974819, 
          0.382584668329802, 0.363334129335034, 0.304878812975166, 0.250050385214014, 
          0.360915639062344, 0.292179198612586, 0.298427811960688, 0.281898921333015, 
          0.349829198358543, 0.366257318558187, 0.607035130772918, 0.373614406614605, 
          0.643217642107474, 0.460693605396553, 0.457065869987518, 0.49677534630308, 
          0.446987133564004, 0.475307857891679, 0.477726348164369, 0.474300153611392, 
          0.473292449331105, 0.478634128826948, 0.473292449331105, 0.474501694467449, 
          0.477625577736341, 0.474703235323507, 0.477020955168168, 0.475207087463651, 
          0.476013250887881, 0.476617873456053, 0.474199383183363, 0.476013250887881, 
          0.476214791743938, 0.475912480459852, 0.474703235323507, 0.474804005751536, 
          0.474602464895478, 0.475307857891679, 0.475610169175766, 0.476013250887881, 
          0.476718643884082, 0.475610169175766, 0.476214791743938, 0.476315562171967, 
          0.474703235323507, 0.475811710031823, 0.475509398747737, 0.474904776179565, 
          0.475005546607593, 0.474804005751536, 0.475509398747737, 0.474904776179565, 
          0.475610169175766, 0.475811710031823, 0.474501694467449, 0.475005546607593, 
          0.474501694467449, 0.473796301471248, 0.475509398747737, 0.473796301471248, 
          0.475509398747737, 0.475106317035622, 0.474804005751536, 0.475408628319708, 
          0.474400924039421, 0.475307857891679, 0.475610169175766, 0.475408628319708, 
          0.475610169175766, 0.475106317035622)
```

Comment: ok thanks. And what exactly do you mean by "match them" ?

Comment: to coincide the parts with peaks to observe how similar are

Comment: You can use `par(new=TRUE)` to keep the device window active. then use another `plot` command to plot the second graph. From here, you can use `xlim` to clip the second graph. This would be the most straight foward way.

Comment: @etienne thanks for "darkblue" :) well spotted, I changed it to "blue" to see the difference between time1 and time2.

Comment: I would look at `ccf` to help you find the lag in d_mx that maximizes the correlation with d_fx

Comment: @emilliman5, could you show me how to implement ccf in my case? I've never used that function before